How to write Filter Expression in Azure Data Copy Activity
I have a filter in the Azure Data Factory pipeline where I need to write a condition expression in the operator to match all file formats. But the 'in' operator is not a regular function.
Items:
@activity('GetMetadata').output.childItems

Condition:
@or(in(item().name, 'file1.txt', 'file03.pdf', 'file113.xml', 'ins222.jpg','AD492.zip','stat2020.csv'))


You can use the below expression in the Filter activity condition to achieve your requirement.
@and(equals(item().type, 'File'),contains(createarray('file1','file03','file113','ins222','AD492','stat2020'),split(item().name,'.')[0]))

You need to have all the required file name patterns as an array for this.
As you want the files of all formats, the above condition first checks whether the current item is a file format or not. Then it checks whether the current file name is in the required file names array or not.
This is my sample Get meta data child items array:
"childItems": [
        {
            "name": "AD492.zip",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "file03.pdf",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "file1.json",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "file1.txt",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "file113.xml",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "ins222.jpg",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "stat2020.csv",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "validation.xlsx",
            "type": "File"
        },
        {
            "name": "zip2.rakesh",
            "type": "File"
        }

Use the above condition in the filter like below.

It gives the required files:

